# How to deploy UDP python server?

Tags: python, python-2.7, deployment, udp, python-2.x

I have a project. It needs to deploy UDP server and Django server.

I know how to deploy Django server. It just sets up with nginx and uwsgi. It will implement my requirement.

But I don't know how to deploy UDP server. This is my UDP server's code:

```
import asyncore
import socket

class EchoHandler(asyncore.dispatcher_with_send):

    def handle_read(self):
        data = self.recv(8192)
        if data:
            self.send(data)

class EchoServer(asyncore.dispatcher):

    def __init__(self, host, port):
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
        self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.set_reuse_addr()
        self.bind((host, port))
        self.listen(5)

    def handle_accept(self):
        pair = self.accept()
        if pair is not None:
            sock, addr = pair
            print 'Incoming connection from %s' % repr(addr)
            handler = EchoHandler(sock)

server = EchoServer('0.0.0.0', 8080)
asyncore.loop()
```

It's not like that django application server hadn't been hard coded ip address and port because ip address and port can be writed in nginx configure file in advance.

So, anyone has good idea to deploy udp server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your UDP server works when you run it in a terminal, but that you don't want to keep a terminal open for the script, what you want is to run your script as a service.

In modern flavours of Linux this can be done in the classic style of SysV shell scripts, or with either upstart or systemd.

This is a large topic and you should read up on how to create unix services from arbitrary scripts (or windows services if that's what you need, which is a very different topic).

EDIT: information and resources on running scripts as services.

Some rudimentary ways of daemonizing the script (running in the background), are to use `disown`, `dtach`, or `screen`. If your script is located at `/path/to/myudp.py` then you could use one of the following:

```
disown python /path/to/myudp.py &
```

or

```
dtach python /path/to/myudp.py
```

or

```
screen python /path/to/myudp.py
```

All three of these are very similar and will start the script from the terminal, but when the terminal closes the script will continue to run. But these will not automatically start when the system boots up, so they are not really considered services. These approaches are good for testing but not for production.

The first way to create a true service out of the script is to create a SysV init script. On Ubuntu you can find these scripts in /etc/init.d/ and in other flavours of linux they might be in /etc/rc.d/. You can read up on creating the scripts here:  http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-write-sys-v-init-script-to-start-stop-service.html and here is a decent template: https://github.com/fhd/init-script-template/blob/master/template (Nota Bene: these scripts will be a little different on each linux distribution).

The next way to create a service from the script is with upstart. If your system is running upstart you are likely on a newish version of Ubuntu, and the upstart script will not work on systems not using upstart for service management. You can read more about upstart here: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html.

The last and newest way is to write a systemd unit file. Again this only works if the system is running systemd to manage its services. You can read up on creating services in systemd at these links: http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/systemd-docs.html and https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Writing_unit_files and http://patrakov.blogspot.com/2011/01/writing-systemd-service-files.html

Comment: May you give me more information? It's interesting.